# Vim - How Recognize Spaces as Tabs (set listchars=tab)

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc, macvim, vim-plugins

I wonder if it is possible to use a configuration for that 
command "set listchars=tab:▒░,trail:·" to "see" 4 spaces as tabs 
and get the effect of the picture below (using real tabs)...

[image]

I use the setting "set expandtab" to Vim use spaces in place 
of tabs. I really need to use spaces instead of tabs, but I would 
keep the functionality above. **There is some form of do this?**

---

Here's how Vim behaves when I use "set expandtab"...

[image]

... I wish he recognized one tab for every 4 spaces like above!

---

```
My setup for tabs...

set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
set expandtab
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following plugins:

- [Indent Guides](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3361)
- [indentLine.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4354)

Comment: I could not use "Indent Guides" in Vim terminal (may need some additional feature of Vim). The "indentLine" worked properly!